# calling a function from action in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm in need of calling a function located in a class stored in app/lib directory before every action (ie. in preExecute action)

In that function I do need a `$this` pointer from an action.

I can do it in a static way - `Classname::functionname()`, however it results with a PHP warning, which I want to avoid.

For now I handle it with

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');     # don't show any errors...
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  # ...but do log them
```

but it's an ugly way..

How can I do it in a dynamic way?

===============

EDIT:

as requested - I add a code to show what am I actually doing with that `$this` pointer

```
...
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(ArticlePeer::PUBLISHED, true);
$articles = ArticlePeer::doSelect($c);
$this->articles = $articles;
...
```

Yes, I know that I can put this Select in preExecute action in every module and it will be working fine. However - I have many modules, and as I have a set of actions that are all the same for all those modules, so putting them in one procedure and just calling that function would be the smartest way... 
Especially when it comes to maintaining the app - It's only one place to change code, instead of a dozen of them...

Comment: "In that function i do need a $this pointer from an action." - could you elaborate what you mean here? Maybe show this "function located in a class"? If I had to guess, I'd say you are looking for `$obj = new Classname(); $obj->functionname();`

Comment: As @fab says, we need more information: what does this function in app/lib? Why do you need `$this` inside this action?

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I've put the sample use of the `$this` pointer.  I've tried the approach suggested by @fab before I posted my question here - the assignment of `$articles` to `$this->articles` failed. That's why I put accent on my need of having access to that pointer in my procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class inside your `app/lib` folder, you simply have to return `$articles`:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(ArticlePeer::PUBLISHED, true);
return ArticlePeer::doSelect($c);
```

Then, inside your `preExecute()`:

```
public function preExecute()
{
  $this->articles = Classname::functionname();
}
```

If you have to return multiple value, you can do it using an array:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(ArticlePeer::PUBLISHED, true);
$articles =  ArticlePeer::doSelect($c);

$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(BookPeer::PUBLISHED, true);
$books =  BookPeer::doSelect($c);

return array(
  'articles' => $articles,
  'books'    => $books,
);
```

End then, use this array to populate your variable inside your action:

```
public function preExecute()
{
  $data = Classname::functionname();

  $this->articles = $data['articles'];
  $this->books    = $data['books'];
}
```

Comment: I knew the answer would be simple, but not that it will be that simple... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of `$this` in a method. Never.

Instead, look at the class how you can access `$articles` from outside, there should be something like `getArticles()`. It looks like the class is a Propel model, those have generated getters like that.

Dependent on what your end goal is, there might be better solutions than instantiating this model, calling the mysterious method and then getting the attribute. After all, classes are not just collections of functions and should not be treated like that. Not repeating code is good, but it has to be done with some sense.